# How to get package names?

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

How can i display all the package names of all apps installed in my phone. Also adding button to open direct setting of that app.

I want to check if a perticular app package is available on phone or not.

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a _particular_ app is installed, or do you want a list of _all_ apps?  Also, what do you mean by "open direct setting of that app"?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

List<ApplicationInfo> packages =   packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
  Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
  Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```